# How do I avoid conflicts in git when merging into a feature branch

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict

We have a branch, which I'll call BR1, and which I'm on initially.  I want to do some work for a future release, and so I pull (and build), and then create a feature branch with:

```
git checkout -b FBR1a
git push -u origin FBR1a
```

I make some changes, commit, and push.  A couple days later, I want to update my branch with the latest changes on BR1, so I don't have any big surprises when I eventually merge back.  So, I switch branches, pull to update, then merge with:

```
git checkout BR1  
git pull
(build)
git checkout FBR1a
git merge BR1
```

All goes fine.  (I know, I could have just pulled from origin directly).

A few days later, I repeat this process, but I get a bunch of conflicts on files *I* did not touch, but were changed on BR1 by someone else, first between my creating FBR1 and my first merge from BR1, and then again between my first merge of BR1 and my second.

So, why would git be reporting these as conflicts if I am not changing the files directly in the feature branch, but only as a result of a merge?

I have gitconfig set to:

```
[pull]
    rebase = true
```

Comment: Was there a history rewrite in BR1? :thinking: Also, it is not specified but I assume you _do not_ have any changes introduced in your local BR1 and so every time you pull into that branch, the branch pointer lands _exactly on the same revision as origin/BR1_, right?

Comment: No, I've done nothing to cause a history rewrite (other than the rebase = true) on pull.  And no I have no local changes.  Or if I did, they would have been pushed to origin/BR1 before the pull, and in any case would not have involved any of the same files.  (The files causing the conflict are help files, which I never modify.)

Comment: Show the commit graph (e.g., `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` output). Merge conflicts mean something has changed on "both sides" since the merge base commit, and the merge base commit is determined by the graph, so "which commit was the merge base" is the most interesting question.